# Implementing OAuth for ODBC

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

I am trying to connect and query our foundry ontology from different Microsoft tools in our own network. I was able to do so using a token as described in the documentation. That works great and it is easy to configure. The problem is that it is associated to only one account and the token expires often.

Reading the documentation I saw the option for OAuth. What is not very clear in the documentation is whether we have to register an application for ODBC and how to do it. When I have had to register applications in the past in cloud environments, the application normally has a returned address that the cloud app hits to authenticate. However, in this case, I don't see how that would help for ODBC from desktop applications like Excel or Access.

Any suggestion or reading would be appreciated

Comment: Peanut Galery Opinion: I've often seen folks create "service accounts" that only have access to the projects/org/data absolutely needed, and then create a long lived token with these service accounts, you can do so by loging in with the service account and generating a token in the user settings.

Comment: @fmsf Thank you! yes, we have thought about that. The thing is that we have hundreds of users, different data pipes, and IT infrastructure restrictions. One of the things we would like to do is be able to audit what user is hitting what pipeline at any given moment and not just the service account showing for all queries. Also, IT does not want to have passwords (or tokens) live forever, so we have to maintain them ourselves and we don't want to do that either for dozens of accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the OAuth flow with the ODBC driver on Windows you can register a third-party application in Foundry (see [docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/platform-security-third-party/register-3pa/)). You can use a public or confidential client, and the redirect URL should be set to `http://127.0.0.1/foundrydriver/oauthredirect`.

Comment: These details are also being added to the [ODBC driver docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/analytics-connectivity/odbc-jdbc-drivers/).

Comment: In the specific case of this question you would generate a public client (since you need to distribute the client_id to your end-users).